# Добавление z-index для каждого элемента в списке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется обычный список вида:

```
<ul id="new">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Как скриптом прописать что у каждого последующего элемента в списке z-index был меньше на 1.

```
<ul id="new">
    <li style="z-index:100;"></li>
    <li style="z-index:99;"></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: А может лучше подумать и сделать что-то другое? Зачем такое вдруг понадобилось?

Comment: Можно конечно использовать child css но этот варинт не работает в ie 8. просто не знаю как еще можно сделать что бы каждый элемент шел ниже слоем предыдущего.

Comment: Я спросил, зачем именно нужно такое размещение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C jquery:

```
var z_index = 100;
$("#new li").each(function(index, domEl){
    $(domEl).css({"z-index": z_index})
    z_index--;
})
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно))